# Powershell -or isn't working -or I'm using it wrong.

Tags: powershell

I've tried to use it both ways and it deleted the files no matter what. Basically if any of the variables are true I don't want it to delete the file, but it does anyway. I know that $Paper= MN and it still deletes the file. I'm obviously doing something wrong.

```
if(!$Paper.equals("MN") -or !$Paper.equals("NJ") -and $extension.equals(".txt")){
Remove-Item $File.FullName -Force -Recurse
write-host $File " has been removed."
}

if($Paper -ne "MN" -or $Paper -ne "NJ" -or $extension -eq ".txt"){
Remove-Item $File.FullName -Force -Recurse
write-host $File " has been removed."
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you need to change all the `-or` to `-and` for both examples. Because otherwise it will always evaluate to true.

Comment: yep. good catch. !$Paper.equals("MN") -or !$Paper.equals("NJ") always evaluates to true.

Comment: Yeah, I think what his train of thought was `If(!($Paper.equals("MN") -or $Paper.equals("NJ")) -and $extension.equals(".txt"))` but didn't have the parenthesis in there to group his -or's together for the -Not statement.

Answer (score 0):

Lets put your first if in a truth table:

!$Paper.equals("MN") i will call that NOT A
!$Paper.equals("NJ") i will call that NOT B
$extension.equals(".txt") i will call that C

your expression is   NOT A OR NOT B AND C = delete

so here is the table:

```
A  B  C  delete
0  0  0  0
0  0  1  1
0  1  0  0
0  1  1  1
1  0  0  0
1  0  1  1
1  1  0  0
1  1  1  1
```

Now looking at this, you should notice, that you are deleting the file when atleast one expression is not true and the file is a txt.

What you wanted to achieve is to use some brackets,

!($Paper.equals("MN") -or $Paper.equals("NJ")) -and $extension.equals(".txt")

New truth table:

NOT(A OR B) AND C = delete

```
A  B  C  delete
0  0  0  0
0  0  1  1 
0  1  0  0
0  1  1  0 
1  0  0  0
1  0  1  0
1  1  0  0
1  1  1  0
```

We could apply De'Morgans law here and turn

> NOT(A OR B) into NOT A AND NOT B

So it will become

> NOT A AND NOT B AND C

```
!$Paper.equals("MN") -and !$Paper.equals("NJ") -and $extension.equals(".txt")
```

Comment: Ok I see what you're saying.if(!$Paper.equals("MN") -and !$Paper.equals("NJ") -or $extension.equals(".txt")){
Remove-Item $File.FullName -Force -Recurse
write-host $File " has been removed."
} I would still use a -or when checking the extension because I want it to delete .txt files no matter if the first two conditions are true or not. Right? Sorry sending from my phone.

Comment: Yes. I misunderstood you then.

Answer (score 0):

"Basically if any of the variables are true I don't want it to delete the file,"

Okay.

```
if ( ( $Paper.equals("MN"), $Paper.equals("NJ"), $extension.equals(".txt") ) -notcontains $true )
  { Remove-Item $File.FullName -Force -Recurse }
```